# AWS Amplify SSL configuration pending

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname-record, amazon-route53

I am setting up AWS Amplify to build, deploy and host one of my application written in Angular. Everything is working with `Amplify` domain. Now I am trying to configure a custom domain  to `Amplify`, but it is showing a message as follows :

```
In order to verify domain ownership, we will look for the following CNAME record associated with your domain. Please verify that the CNAME record exists in your Domain Name Server (DNS) file
```

and there is a `CNAME` entry is showing there. Actually I have added a `Hosted Zone` in `Route 53` and the `CANME` entry is already added there while I create the domain/subdomain. I am not sure what needs to be done now. How can I pass through the domain verification ? I have registered my domain at `GoDaddy` anf added the AWS NS records there.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/66#issuecomment-525009758

Answer (score 0):

What you did, sounds technically correct to me. I have seen this and in most cases it helped to remove and re-add the domain to Amplify. There is no way (I know) to just restart verification.

It seems that in the first run, your domain was not validated successfully (enough). Because your domain is not hosted within AWS itself, you'll need to make the change *reasonably* fast. In my case, more than 30 minutes between adding the CNAME and the validation "process" was too much.

Officially, the timeframe is 60 Minutes before the validation times out. But the message does not change, so wl'll never know. And it's not really documented.